# olimex A20 image using yocto project-olimex A20 Boot Chain/Boot sequence

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bootloader

I have already managed to build an image for olimex a20 SOM-EVB using yocto build system but the output generated in /tmp/deploy/images is not a single .img ,file it has multiple files .i searched the whole documentation to find anything related to boot chain but unfortunately i couldnot find anything that would help.I found the bootchain for stm32mp157 but couldnot find any document for olimex a20

i tried to compress all the files and burn them on sd card using balena etcher but it didnot bootup .
is there any way to burn the generated files on sd card ?

Comment: Writing to SD card (or any flash device) does not involve any chemical reaction (unlike writing to optical discs), so "*burn*" is the wrong verb to use. If you want to write a single image to the SD card, then you first have to explicitly create one, e.g. using a tool such as genimage.

Comment: Your confusing title indicates that you first need to understand the layout of the SD card expected by your board. Manufacturers of SoCs each have their own boot schemes, and how/where the bootloader(s) should be stored on a nSD card (e.g. raw sectors versus FAT file). Read manuals and/or examine a prebuilt/working SD card to understand what partitions & filesystems are used, and where the binaries that were generated should be written. You need such understanding for using genimage & etcher, or manually writing each file to the SD card.